# How to only allow the user who "owns" the data to edit it?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

I know how to use the annotation to only allow authorized users or users in certain roles but how can I allow ONLY the individual that owns the data to edit it.

If I have user foo and user bar.  Foo can go to `localhost/User/Edit/Foo` and put in his details.  How can I prevent Foo from going to `localhost/User/Edit/Bar` and editing Bars info as well?  Stack Overflow gives you a Page Not Found if you try to edit a profile that's not yours.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controllers all have access to the User.Identity object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

You can use this information to determine the currently authenticated user. Then you can check whether the user has permission with something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo(int id)
{
    if (DatabaseService.DoesUserHavePermission(User.Identity.Name, id) == false)
        return View("ErrorPage");

    return View("SuccessPage", yourdata);
}
```

Alternatively, you can have methods that just return data for whatever the currently authenticated user is:

```
public ActionResult Foo(int id)
{
    var data = DatabaseService.GetDataForUser(User.Identity.Name);

    return View(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents to [@mfanto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468170/how-to-only-allow-the-user-who-owns-the-data-to-edit-it/5468254#5468254), since you're using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could use the new `HttpNotFoundResult` like:

```
return new HttpNotFoundResult();

//Or using the shorthand method
return HttpNotFound();
```

instead of `return View("ErrorPage")` if what you want is a `404` redirect